# create custom plugins that checks @SwaggerDefinition and it's properties for sonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to check the validation of @SwaggerAnnotation(info = @info) and add it as a rule in plugins
and i cant find any resource that help me to build that code
if anyone can help me to build this custom rule please write your suggestion and your code
thank you.